# Auto update cart totals on cart item quantity change in Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I'm trying to update the cart total every time the quantity of an product in cart is increased or decreased automatically. I tried below code but it doesn't work all the time only works once after the cart page is refreshed;

```
function update_cart_refresh_update_qty() {
    if (is_cart()) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        $('.qty').on('change', function(){
            setTimeout(function() {//This is set, so it gives the update cart button time to enable from disable mode
                $('input[name="update_cart"]').trigger('click');
            }, 2000);

        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'update_cart_refresh_update_qty');
```

I would want the cart total (update cart button to be triggered) to be updated every time there is a change in product quantity.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use it as a document.body delegated event *(on `change` and `input` events)* as follow:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'update_cart_on_item_qty_change');
function update_cart_on_item_qty_change() {
    if (is_cart()) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        $(document.body).on('change input', '.qty', function(){
            $('button[name="update_cart"]').trigger('click');
            // console.log('Cart quantity changed…');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Similar: [Avoid a function to only runs once on button click in WooCommerce cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56213249/avoid-a-function-to-only-runs-once-on-button-click-in-woocommerce-cart/56216986#56216986)

Comment: In this code when I click on selector and increase the quantity to 1 it does not work and after that when click again and value increased to 2 work.